# pg_query_params returning false

Tags: postgresql, php-7, php-pgsql

I am using this code to check if an email already exists in the DB, but it returns 'false' everytime (it's working on another website).

```
pg_query_params("SELECT * FROM a_user WHERE LOWER(user_email) = $1", $params);
```

After the execution of query, value of $params is changing, not sure how.

Comment: Do you have the logs of the database server to check what happens on the DB server side ?

Comment: 2017-10-01 12:39:49 UTC [18136-1] postgres@asif_online ERROR:  syntax error at or near "=" at character 29

Comment: 2017-10-01 12:39:49 UTC [18136-2] postgres@asif_online STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM a_user WHERE  = $1

Comment: @greg Here you go. LOWER(user_email) is getting cut out of the statement.